# How to exit the program when input is not in correct form in C?

Tags: c, linux

My code is about taking input from the user and store in the array. Each element of the array will contain the name, age, and species of the pet.
I don't know why it keeps printing the error "Invalid input for name" even though my input was a string. It works for int but not with the string

```
    int petCount = 1;

    while (1) {
            if (scanf("%s", array[petCount].name) != 1) {
                    printf("Invalid input for name.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            if (scanf("%d", &array[petCount].age) != 1) {
                    printf("Invalid input for age.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            if (scanf("%s", array[petCount].species) != 1) {
                    printf("Invalid input for species.\n");
                    exit(1);
            }
            petCount++;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < petCount; i++){
            printf("%s, %d, %s\n", array[i].name, array[i].age, array[i].species );
    }
    free(array);
```

}

Input:

```
Type name, age, species on each line (press Ctrl+D to finish):
Eve
9
cat
```

Output:

```
Invalid input for name.
```

Comment: (maybe) O/T, array indexing in C starts at 0, not 1. If you already know this, please don't fight it. Beyond that, please provide a [mre], including a compliable example and your exact inputs.

Comment: @Evelyn Thai, `array[petCount].species` is no good.  Post a [mcve].

Comment: OT: Congratulations for verifying the return value from `scanf()`! You'll need some way to break out of that infinite loop, though... AND, you won't want to `free()` the array, either...

Answer (score 2):

1. You use a loop and terminate the *program* it if input doesn't match the format string.  You usually terminate the *loop* by either fixing the number iterations up front, or you have a way to signify you are done.  In this case, I am using invalid format (i.e. not reading the 3 fields in) for example triggered with CTRL-D and then use `break` (or `goto`) to terminate the loop.
2. Arrays are zero-indexed in C.
3. Always includes a maximum field width when reading strings with `scanf()`.  Otherwise your code is subject to buffer overflow.
4. Always use a temporary variable when using `realloc()` otherwise you have data loss if `realloc()` fails.
5. `malloc()` probably uses chunk allocation internally so doubling the size opposed to just allocating an extra element per loop iteration many not buy you much.
6. For `age` consider using an `unsigned` type, say, `unsigned char`.  Otherwise you may need code to deal with negative values which may not make sense.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NAME_LEN 10
#define SPECIES_LEN 10
#define str(s) str2(s)
#define str2(s) #s

struct Pet {
    char name[NAME_LEN+1];
    int age;
    char species[SPECIES_LEN+1];
};

int main(void) {
    size_t size = 1;
    struct Pet *array = malloc(sizeof *array * size);
    int petCount = 0;
    for(;; petCount++) {;
        if (scanf("%" str(NAME_LEN) "s%d%" str(SPECIES_LEN) "s", array[petCount].name,  &array[petCount].age, array[petCount].species) != 3)
            break;
        if (petCount + 1 == size) {
            size *= 2;
            struct Pet *tmp = realloc(array, sizeof(struct Pet) * size);
            if (!tmp) {
                printf("Memory reallocation failed.\n");
                exit(1);
            }
            array = tmp;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < petCount; i++)
        printf("%s, %d, %s\n", array[i].name, array[i].age, array[i].species );
    free(array);
}
```

and example run:

```
bob 
1
jack
jane
2
russell 
<CTRL-D>
bob, 1, jack
jane, 2, russell
```

Comment: Thanks for your code, but it didn't exit when the input was in incorrect form

Comment: I showed you a working example.  What input did you use to conclude otherwise?

Comment: Nice answer. UV'ing. But, just for fun, try reversing the `realloc()` and `scanf()` and eliminating the `malloc()`... `size` starts at `0` and `array = NULL`... Not many "coding" questions since ChatGPT is writing code for newbies these days... `:-)`

Comment: The problem is that it will print out all of the inputs even though the inputs are not in the correct form. For example, the name and species of the pet should be string, but if you type an integer, the program still accepts it and print it out.

Comment: All input is a string (`%s` is a word actually) so "42" is a valid word.  If you want to disallow numbers then you need to use a different format string `%[^0-9 ]` for example.

Comment: @Fe2O3 I did realize that but the `size *= 2` let me to believe that op is start with a non-zero array.